# how to add a column with specific string depending on 4th column with awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file in which the 4th column has numbers.

If 4th column is greater than 2 I want to add 5th column corresponding as `gain`; otherwise, the 5th column will have the string `loss`.

Input

```
1   762097  6706109 6
1   7202143 7792617 3
1   8922949 9815420 1
1   10502346    11074110    3
1   11188922    12267136    1
1   12566829    13910626    3
```

Desired output:

```
1   762097  6706109 6   gain
1   7202143 7792617 3   gain
1   8922949 9815420 1   loss
1   10502346    11074110    3   gain
1   11188922    12267136    1   loss
1   12566829    13910626    4   gain
```

How should I do this with awk?

Comment: This is unbelievably basic,did you actually try anything ?

Comment: I could only add the gain string.. but not the loss.. I was not able to comprehend the esle part

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` like this:

```
$ awk '{print $0, ($4>2?"gain":"lose")}' file
1   762097  6706109 6 gain
1   7202143 7792617 3 gain
1   8922949 9815420 1 lose
1   10502346    11074110    3 gain
1   11188922    12267136    1 lose
1   12566829    13910626    3 gain
```

As you see, it is printing the full line (`$0`) followed by a string. This string is determined by the value of `$4` using a ternary operator.

Comment: perfect..  @fedorqui .. I have brush up these stuffs .. sorry for my lame queries

Comment: Another similar way `awk '$(NF+1)=$4>2?"gain":"lose"' file`